# Sort Table Data Default Issue

Tags: javascript, jsp, sorting, onclick

I am trying to sort the table data. I am able to sort the data of the column onClick using a doSort function in Javascript but couldn't sort the data default on table load

Any ideas?

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="sortcol sortasc" onclick="doSort(0);">Code</th>
    <th class="sortcol sortasc" onclick="doSort(1);">Name</th>
</tr>
```

Thanks for your time !!

Comment: What javascript library/package are you using to setup the table sorting?  Are you using jquery at all?

Comment: I didn't use Jquery or other Javascript Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using jquery or a table sorting library, then you need to rely on when the browser signals that it's finished loading, and then call your own sorting method.  Something like this in your page should get you started:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    doSort(0);
  });
</script>
```